# ERROR:Failed to connect to atlas.hashicorp.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: command-line, proxy, vagrant, ping

Can someone help me with this ?
I am getting this error while setting **vagrant up** for **ubuntu/trusty64**

```
ERROR:Failed to connect to atlas.hashicorp.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Later I realised that I **can't even ping any website from my command prompt**, but in a browser, I can access these sites. I am behind a corporate **proxy server**.
Following is the exact error what I am getting in my power shell. I am on a windows 10 machine.

```
 Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
`==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found.
Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox 
default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error: Failed to connect to atlas.hashicorp.com port 443: Connection refused`
```

Answer (score 4):

you should setup your proxy - your browser probably has the setting but not your CLI tools

you should make sure to set the following variables with your proxy information

```
export http_proxy=http://your.proxyhost.server:port/
export https_proxy=https://your.proxyhost.server:port/
```

Comment: I don't know where can I set the above variables. will you please be more specific about your answer ?

Comment: you set it from your Command Line - it can be in your bash file. but to simplify just run the command before you execute vagrant up

Comment: This is not a proxy problem, it happens even if the proxy is set up correctly.

Comment: My bad, with the proxy configurations in place it works. I am having certificate problems now, but that is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for users with direct connection to Internet:

Go to Mu$tdie firewall settings, add allowing rules for:
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin\curl.exe
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin\vagrant.exe